# IIS 7 -- how to track down mysterious network & cpu usage?

Tags: iis-7, performance-tuning

I've got a 64-bit Server 2008 (R1) box running IIS. Users were complaining about extremely slow-loading pages. After digging around I found:

1. After isolating the box so only one user was able to connect, each web request caused the CPU to jump to 30% for about two seconds, even on the simplest of pages. Looking at the code, no obvious reason for this usage is apparent.
2. NewRelic shows > 10s lost to "networking", even though all the access is over a 100-meg LAN, and perfmon shows a network Output Queue Length of zero.

We can't find anything in the code that should cause so much CPU activity, or any answer to why NewRelic thinks there's a network problem.

Looking for suggestions of where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 enabled a new network feature by default Scalable Networking Pak. I think this feature causes more issues than it solves.
Here is 2 articles refer to this issue:
[TCP Chimney](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/dd277645.aspx)
[Microsoft Support article: KB951037](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037)

Answer (score 0):

You might also find [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis/) useful here. The name is a little too specific actually, cause the feature enables tracing any type of request.

Tess Ferrandez over at MSDN wrote a brilliant article about [performance troubleshooting with Failed Request Tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/08/19/troubleshooting-a-performance-issue-with-failed-request-tracing-and-appcmd-in-iis7.aspx), definitely worth a read in this type of scenario